# How to get file owner and other properties in python in windows environment

Tags: python

I searched all over and found this

```
from os import stat
from pwd import getpwuid
filename='test.txt'
def find_owner(filename):
    return getpwuid(stat(filename).st_uid).pw_name
```

But in windows environment this is giving error

```
ImportError: No module named pwd
```

P.S I dont want to install any additional module and PWD isn't an inbuilt module. So a solution where there is no need to install any module is required.

The question is unique as the marked duplicate doesn't has an accepted answer first or all and then that answer too shows dependency on third party module which I clearly said I don't want.

Comment: have you installed `pwd`

Comment: I dont wanna use any external module

Comment: I think that's available as default in UNIX envi

Comment: You need to install pwd first

Comment: Please read the PS part

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? The `pwd` module is about the (unix-specific) user/password database. Your question title seems to indicate that you actually want to do something different.

Comment: I want to get the owner of file in windows environment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the owner of the file in the windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41280639/how-to-get-the-owner-of-the-file-in-the-windows-7)

Comment: This could also be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8086412/howto-determine-file-owner-on-windows-using-python-without-pywin32

Comment: Please check the updated question